# How to put drop down menu inside jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I try to put a drop down menu inside Jssor slider but, the menu cannot drop when inside it.

The following is the code:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = { $AutoPlay: false };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', options);
    });
</script>
<style>
        .form-style {
            position: relative;
            top:10px;
            left:10px;
        }
        .image-style {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 300px; float: right;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="1.jpg" class="image-style" />
            <form class="form-style" action="index" method="post" >
                Admin Mode: <select name="admin_mode">
                    <option value="on">on</option>
                    <option value="off">off</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="2.jpg" class="image-style" />
            <form class="form-style" action="index" method="post" >
                Admin Mode: <select name="admin_mode">
                    <option value="on">on</option>
                    <option value="off">off</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Any conflict that might result the inability to drop down?

regards,
ethereal1m

Comment: This is a bug, I have got it fixed and uploaded. Please download the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, I don't know exactly why it is happening. But while figuring out what's going on, one solution could be: change the select dropdown box by radio box, e.g:

```
<input type="radio" name="AdminMode" value="on">on<br>
<input type="radio" name="AdminMode" value="off">off
```

I already check it, and it is working. If it's not, you should modify the function uc(c) included in the jssor.slider.mini.js. This function is triggered onmousedown. You have to change this from:

```
function uc(c){
    var b=a.nf(c).tagName;
    !N && b!="INPUT" && b!="TEXTAREA" && sc() && tc(c)
}
```

to become like:

```
function uc(c){
    var b=a.nf(c).tagName;
    !N && b!="TEXTAREA" && sc() && tc(c)
}
```

Check this link [example](http://sanmarx2.eu5.org/examples/Jssor/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!